# superslides jquery plugin customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi All,

I need help customizing this jquery plugin so that the pagination looks like links with text in them instead of like the default.

So basically the output on the page should be: Link1 | Link2 | Link3,etc. I have tried creating an Array and returning that Array to the addPaginationItem() function, however, all attempts have been very unsuccessful.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been struggling with it.

2 main functions Code that I need to manipulate looks as follows:

```
   addPaginationItem = function(i) {
  if (!(i >= 0)) {
    i = _this.size() - 1;
  }
  return $pagination.append($("<a>", {
    href: "#" + i,
    "class": _this.current === $pagination.children().length ? "current" : void 0
  }));
};
addPagination = function() {
  var array, last_index;
  if (!_this.options.pagination || _this.size() === 1) {
    return;
  }
  if ($(el).find("." + _this.options.classes.pagination).length) {
    last_index = $pagination.children().last().index();
    array = $children;
  } else {
    last_index = 0;
    array = new Array(_this.size() - last_index);
    $pagination = $pagination.appendTo(_this.el);
  }
  return $.each(array, function(i) {
    return addPaginationItem(i);
  });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: We need to see some code to help

Comment: I have updated my question with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my own problem. I think I just needed to walk away from the code for a bit.
Thanks all. I added the following code which solved my problem

```
addPaginationItem = function(i,linkText) {

  if (!(i >= 0)) {
    i = _this.size() - 1;
  }

  return $pagination.append($("<a>", {
    href: "#" + i,
    text:linkText,
    "class": _this.current === $pagination.children().length ? "current" : void 0
  }));
};

addPagination = function() {
  var array, last_index;
  var hrefText = ['test1','test2','test3','test4'];

  if (!_this.options.pagination || _this.size() === 1) {
    return;
  }
  if ($(el).find("." + _this.options.classes.pagination).length) {
    last_index = $pagination.children().last().index();
    array = $children;
  } else {
    last_index = 0;
    array = new Array(_this.size() - last_index);
    $pagination = $pagination.appendTo(_this.el);
  }

  $.each(hrefText,function(intIndex,objValue) {
    linkText = objValue;
     return addPaginationItem(intIndex,linkText)
  });

};
```